# Hiding view when WKWebView has finished loading swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I'm trying to hide the launch screen once the WKWebView finshes loading. I've found a way to detect when the WKWebView has finished loading with the `didFinish` delegate, but I'm stuck on hiding the launch screen. At the moment, it sets the `webViewFinishedLoading` to true once WKWebView has finished loading, and in `ContentView.swift`, It should only show the view if `webViewFinishedLoading` is set to false. But right now it only shows the launch screen even after WKWebView finishes loading. Here's my code:

`ContentView.swift`:

```
var webViewFinishedLoading = false
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
       SwiftUiWebView(url: URL(string: "myUrl"))
       ZStack {
          if (!webViewFinishedLoading) {
             ....
          }
       }
    }
}
```

`WebView.swift`

```
....
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if (webView.isLoading) {
       return
    }
    print("Done Loading")
    webViewFinishedLoading = true
}
....
```

I know that `didFinish` gets called because I see "Done Loading" in my debug console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `View` won't know to reload unless it is triggered with something like a `@State` property or an `ObservableObject`. You haven't really provided enough code from your `SwiftUiWebView`  to show everything, but here's the gist of what needs to happen:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var webViewFinishedLoading = false

    var body: some View {
       SwiftUiWebView(url: URL(string: "myUrl"), finishedLoading: $webViewFinishedLoading)
       ZStack {
          if (!webViewFinishedLoading) {
             ....
          }
       }
    }
}
```

```
struct SwiftUiWebView : UIViewRepresentable {
  var url: URL
  var finishedLoading: Binding<Bool>

  //...
}
```

Then, you will need to pass that `finishedLoading` Binding to your web view delegate and set its `.wrappedValue` to `true` when you're done loading:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if (webView.isLoading) {
       return
    }
    print("Done Loading")
    finishedLoading.wrappedValue = true
}
```

Because it's tied to a `@State` variable, your view will know to refresh.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the delegate method `didFinish' to get called, I needed to implement the WebView like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    @Binding var isLoading: Bool

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let wkwebView = WKWebView()
        wkwebView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        wkwebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    
        return wkwebView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView
        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.isLoading = true
        }
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            parent.isLoading = false
        }
    }
}
```

Then it can be called like this:

```
@State private var isLoading = false
//...
ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: $isLoading, style: .large)
WebView(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com)!, isLoading: $isLoading)
```